# How to run chrome extension in background automatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a chrome extension.
I have a popup.html and also a background.js file.
I want to create a countdown timer and also want it to run automatically.
but the background.js file cannot access the popup.html.
How to run scripts in backgrounds and automatically change the DOM?

popup.html:

```
<span class="time">20:00</span>
<script src="background.js"></script>
```

background.js:

```
startTimer = (duration, display) => {
  let time = duration, minutes, seconds;


setInterval(() => {
  minutes = parseInt(time / 60, 10);
  seconds = parseInt(time % 60, 10);

  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  display.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  if (--time < 0) {
    time = duration;
  }
 }, 1000);
}

window.onload = () => {
  let duration = 60 * .1, display = document.querySelector('.time');  
  startTimer(duration, display);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your script is just a normal script that runs inside the popup page.
Just because it's named background.js it doesn't magically become a background script.

A real [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) must be declared in manifest.json:

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false
}
```

It creates a **separate hidden background page** (or *event page* when using `"persistent": false`) where that background script will run and will have direct access to DOM of that background page (not to the popup). To inspect/debug the background script click the background page on chrome://extensions page when it's in developer mode: [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029).

Another problem is that the popup exists only when it's shown so you will have to find another way of showing the timer. For example a separate small window (opened via chrome.windows.create) or a small text badge on the extension icon (set via chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText), for which you can find examples by googling.